# Getting (geometric) 95% CI from geometric mean and geometric SD (after log-transformation)

Tags: confidence-interval, mean, lognormal-distribution, logarithm

I am conducting a meta-analysis with a skewed distribution. To address this issue, I transformed the "marker" data into a log-scale, "ln marker".

I obtained **the (geometric) mean and standard deviation of ln marker** from one article.

My goal is **to find the 95% CI of ln marker**. To do this, I **transformed the geometric mean and geometric standard deviation back into log-scale**, so they became the mean and standard deviation of ln marker again. I then used the formula **"mean +/- 1.96 SD/sqrt(N)**" to calculate the 95% CI of ln marker, assuming the normal distribution by log transformation.

However, I am unsure if this is the right way to get the 95% CI of ln marker with geometric mean and SD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that approach seems reasonable. Two notes.

- Your equation for the CI assumes a large sample size. You really should use the critical value from the t distribution (which accounts for sample size) and not 1.96 (which is correct only for large samples).
- Your CI is in the log scale. Back transform both confidence limits to get a a confidence interval in the scale of the original data